# prevent mainloop() from keep running when using subplots form matplotlib in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am using subplot of matplot lib to plot figures inside some function. But it keeps my window form closing and keeps mainloop running as i have shown in image also.

This is my code

```html
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_w = tk.Tk()

fig, (fig1,fig2,fig3,fig4) = plt.subplots(4, figsize=(16,14)) 

my_w.mainloop()
```

when i remove this line

```
 fig, (fig1,fig2,fig3,fig4) = plt.subplots(4, figsize=(16,14))
```

then on closing windows, then it works. So how to prevent this.

[image]

Here i run the graph.py and windows shows up, now when i close the windows, still the cmd prompt shows it is running and prevents me from exiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options to fix the issue:

1. use "Agg" as the default backend

```py
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use("Agg")

my_w = tk.Tk()

fig, (fig1,fig2,fig3,fig4) = plt.subplots(4, figsize=(16,14))

my_w.mainloop()
```

2. use `matplotlib.figure.Figure` instead

```py
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

my_w = tk.Tk()

fig = Figure(figsize=(16,14))
ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4 = fig.subplots(4)

# create a canvas for the figure
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=my_w)
# draw the plots
canvas.draw()
# show the plots
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

my_w.mainloop()
```

Comment: but then neither plt.show() or fig.show() works which is inside a function used to create plots.

Comment: @mark22 My propose is based on your provided code.  If you have other requirements, please edit your question to state it clearly.

Comment: to show a graph i generall use plt.show(). but i used your second approach and now when closing the windows, code also exist but it is not showing graph windows in screen when i use fig.show().

Comment: If i use plt.show below line fig, (fig1,fig2,fig3,fig4) = plt.subplots(4, figsize=(16,14)) , a blank figure is shown on screen with four subplots. But using your second solution, i don't get any figure. How to show graph on screen?

Comment: @mark22 Solution #2 updated.